# Closed form for generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

I'm really not sure how to solve these type of questions could somebody lead me in the right direction?

1. Find a closed form for these generating functions

$$(a)\quad u_n = 3n^2+4n+5 \quad for \quad n=0,1,2,... $$
$$(b) \quad u_n  = {n+7 \choose4} \quad for \quad n=0,1,2,...$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is usually to use the formula
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}.
$$
You can express $3n^2+4n+5$ as a linear combination of $\binom{n+2}{2},\binom{n+1}{1},\binom{n+0}{0}$, thereby solving part (a).

You can solve part (b) in a similar way, but there is a shortcut. We know what $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+4}{4} x^n$ equals to. Notice that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+7}{4} x^n = \frac{1}{x^3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+7}{4} x^{n+3} = \frac{1}{x^3} \sum_{n=3}^\infty \binom{n+4}{4} x^n = \frac{1}{x^3} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+4}{4} x^n - \sum_{n=0}^2 \binom{n+4}{4} x^n \right].
$$

Comment: So for part (a) is the linear combination considered "closed form"? I understand how you got there but i'm not sure why that answers the question

Comment: Keep pondering the issue.

Comment: It's right in front of me, d'oh!

Comment: Last question..for (b) how does the first line work?

Comment: The first equality is just multiplying and dividing by $x^3$. The second is substituting $m = n+3$ and then renaming $m$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the generating function
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(3\,n^2+4\,n+5)t^n
= 3\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2\,t^n+4\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\,t^n+5\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\tag{1}
$$
But a bit of calculus and the identity 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n=\frac{1}{1-t}\tag{2}
$$
gives us
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2\,t^n&=\frac{t(t+1)}{(1-t)^3} &
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\,t^n&=\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Can you use (2) to prove (3)? Can you plug the identities from (3) into (1) to obtain the answer?